# php page isn't working on centos but is working on windows

Tags: php, angularjs, centos

```
//json_decode command reads the data as a string
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fname);
$mname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->mname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lname);
$addr1 = mysql_real_escape_string($data->addr1);
$addr2 = mysql_real_escape_string($data->addr2);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($data->city);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($data->state);
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($data->zip);
$cn = mysql_real_escape_string($data->cn);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);
$Whatsapp = mysql_real_escape_string($data->Whatsapp);
$Emailcheck = mysql_real_escape_string($data->Emailcheck);
$SMS = mysql_real_escape_string($data->SMS);

//database connections
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" ,"studyhour"); 

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO customerinfo
(`Firstname`, `Middlename`, `Lastname`, `Address1`, `Address2`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`, `Contact`, `Email`, `Whatsapp`, `Emailcheck`, `SMS` )
VALUES('".$fname."','".$mname."','".$lname."','".$addr1."','".$addr2."','".$city."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$cn."','".$email."','".$Whatsapp."','".$Emailcheck."','".$SMS."')");

mysqli_close($link);
```

I am trying to insert data into database using AngularJS and php. My data was successfully inserted in WAMP stack but it is not getting inserted in Lamp stack. This script is worked successfully on my windows apache server but when I try to open it in Centos apache server it says "The ***.***.***.*** page isn’t working". I ran the same code but I don't know where I went wrong.

when i submit the form I am getting this :

[image]

Comment: Maybe your Linux box has a more current version of PHP. Those `mysql_*` functions are ancient history and not supported in the recent releases.

Comment: Check your log files, and stop mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions (move fully to `mysqli_` or `PDO` since `mysql_` has long been deprecated and has been removed in PHP 7).

Comment: You are trying to escape strings first with `mysql` then you are querying using `mysqli`. That is wrong. Use `mysqli` only.
Also, you can write query like, `"INSERT INTO table_name (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES ( $fname , $lname)"`
Note that I haven't done full query. This is just more clear to see what is querying exactly.